# OpenElec as DLNA Client

Tags: openelec

I've been googling around and trying for myself but I don't find a solution. I have OpenElec on my Raspberry Pi and in my home network there is a Synology Diskstation acting as a DLNA Server. I am using it with my Playstation 3 and my Philips TV as Clients. Now I also want the Pi to act as a Client, but I can only find stuff on how to use the Pi as a Server. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like openELEC includes XBMC, [which has DNLA client capabilities](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=UPnP).

Comment: I just found out how to do it myself, you have to add it as a video source. Somehow I expected a menu to be somewhere where all DLNA sources are listed since all my other devices work that way. It's working fine now.